# Inceed - opposite word for "exceed"

Tags: word-request

I found a question in EL&U site asking about a word opposite to "exceed". I came up with one, though I am sure there is no such word in the dictionary.

Origin of "exceed" - 
"Ex" (out) + "cedere" (go)

Opposite of that - "In" + "cedere" = Inceed

Please comment about this word - inceed

Comment: Could be mixed up with **increase** or [incide](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/INCIDE?r=66) and phonetically to "in seed" (idiom: in the state of bearing ripened seeds). In brevis, it does't work, and you won't win the bounty with that suggestion.

Comment: If the prefix is Latin (as it is in this case), you should create an opposite with another Latin prefix. Also, I agree with Mari-Lou; you can invent words if you want to, but, generally speaking, those making single word requests are not looking for an invented word, but rather a legitimate word that can be found in dictionaries.

Answer (score 1):

Prefix **in** can  indicate an impossibility (for example: inflexible -> "that cannot be bent") or the absence of something (inconvenient-> that is not convenient) so using **in** might be confusing  and probably no what you mean.

A word meaning the opposite of exceed is already used in popular English: "deceed", so why create a new one? It has not yet made its way into the official dictionaries but it can be found in the [Urban dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Deceed) and in Merriam Webster's New Words & Slang with the following example:

> [When the temperature deceeds the setpoint, the furnace will be turned on.](http://nws.merriam-webster.com/opendictionary/newword_display_cat.php?cat=miscellaneous&last=3820)

and we can hear:

> [Books that Deceeded your Expectations](http://www.goodreads.com/list/show/5243.Books_that_Deceeded_your_Expectations)

or there:

> [Is there an event system that tells me when a value is exceeded or deceeded?](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/202902-Is-there-an-event-system-that-tells-me-when-a-value-is-exceeded-or-deceeded)

and there:

> [Estimates of costs can be exceeded or deceeded by 15 %](http://www.infotecs.net/about/terms.php).

Comment: I hope it doesn't catch on.  I don't think we need a word for this.  I'd use:  *drops below*, *fell below*, *changes* or *goes out of range*, and *vary* in your examples.

Comment: In Italian (which, you know, is based on Latin) we use "mancare" (to miss) as the opposite of "eccedere" (to exceed). In the case of "Books that Missed your Expectations" it seems meaningful to me, but maybe because I am not a native speaker. Another Italian opposite is "difettare" (to be defective of).